# elasticsearch select with where clause for multiple table using java api

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch

I would like to implement the below sql query in elasticsearch using java API :-

```
select name, dob from emp e, address a where e.id=1 and e.city = a.city_name and e.state = a.state_name;
```

I have written the code to fetch from one table like this :

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", empId))
            .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("city", "delhi")));

SearchResponse responseEmpDetails = client.prepareSearch(BaseUtility.getIndexName())
                .setTypes(BaseUtility.getEmpType())
                .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setQuery(queryBuilder)
                .setFrom(0).setSize(500).setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

Could anyone please help me how to write above sql query using java API? Thanks in advance

Comment: I may be wrong. The point is elasticsearch is a search engine which doesnot really work on relations. In the above sql query you are trying to create relationships between multiple tables. I dont know how is your document structure looks like in elasticsearch. I think you should index data from sql based on these relations and do query on those documents.

Comment: there's no joins in ES, you probably need to store city and employee in the same document